# yii2 htaccess allow direct access for a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

I'm working on a yii2 advance application project. I have an `.htaccess` file with this content in my project root:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L] 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

This will hide `frontend/web` and `backend/web` from url([official yii wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/)).

But, now I need to access **just** `test.php` file in my project root directly(without applying MVC structure rules). In fact, I want to access `mydomain.com/test.php` directly. How can I do this?

Note that **I don't want to open direct access for any other files.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want a direct access to a specific file you can place it inside the `frontend/web` directory and that's it, the rules you have defined will work for the hiding of `frontend/web`, you can access it with `mydomain.com/test.php`.